# dm-zero device mount errors

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-mapper

I am trying to create a dm-zero device and mount it,but getting the following errors during mount.I have been stuck here for very long. Any help will be appreciated.

**Error**

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/zero_1,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>          In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>          dmesg | tail  or so

steps I followed are:

1. dmsetup create zero_1 --table '0 20000 zero'
2. mkfs -t ext2 /dev/mapper/zero_1
3. mount -t ext2 /dev/mapper/zero_1 /mnt

dmesg says:

> [ 2547.110310] EXT2-fs (dm-0): error: can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev dm-0.

Answer (score 0):

Really? dm-zero creates device that returns only `0`s. So you will never see ext2 filesystem.

Comment: could you elobrate why I am getting this error and what needs to be done.

Comment: First, could you tell us why are you using dm-zero? What are you trying to do?